# Basic jQuery questions re. blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload with Java

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, blueimp

I'm working with GWT Java, I'm new to jQuery. I don't really know what to search for to clarify this problem. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.
Originally, I wanted a multi file upload form in GWT, but the GWT FormPanel
only accepts 1 file at a time.  So I'm looking at blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload.

There's code here:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine-Java
for using blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload with App Engine in Java. The server side code seems to make sense, but I can't test it as the front end seems to do absolutely nothing.

I include the jQuery code my_jquery_functions.js

in the HTML head, just after jquery-1.8.2.min.js

I've read basic stuff about  jQuery which says that typical jQuery syntax is for an event handler:
$(selector).action()

But the code here ( at code link above) starts with:
$(function() {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload();

I would expect such code to be called by a click of an upload button, but there's no such button, only a browse button, & this is not referenced in the HTML. Why hasn't  the form got an upload 
button?

If I add:     alert("jQ called");   near top of the jQuery function
there is no alert, confirming that the function never gets called.

Am I mising something or is this sample code rubbish?

Comment: How do you call jQuery? From your GWT code?

Comment: As I understand it, in most common usage, jQuery should be called as an event handler, direct from html, nothing to do with GWT. But, calling jQuery from GWT? I have moved away from GWT here, because GWT FormPanel doesn't allow multi file uploads from a form, that's why I am turning to jQuery. I suppose you can call jQuery from GWT's JSNI, maybe use GWT's UIbinder with an html form for multi file upload, instead of GWT FormPanel? Do you know a code sample that does it this way? The pure JS/Java sample would be better. Unfortunately, the author is not replying to questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you pointed to uses input type="file". This input is presented as a "Browse" button in browsers. So this code does exactly what it should.

The event does not fire in jQuery because you never tell it to run. You should have something like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {...}
```

to tell jQuery to execute when the page loads.

Comment: I knew about that from jQuery tutorials. The jQ is not getting called. How should it work? Is browse button supposed to trigger the call for action URL then file name selection the trigger for upload?

Comment: You may need to call your JavaScript from within your GWT code to make it execute. You can either inject it with GWT's ScriptInjector, or put your JavaScript in a native method:  https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI

Comment: I just made a non-gwt version (just index.html & a jQ file) and the jQuery is still not called. I will take a look at the original blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload sample, presumably the jQ gets called here